# Deleted tables is show

Tags: database, wordpress

I used a plugin to transfer a wordpress site from one hosting to another, to the place of an existing site… when migrating, the prefix of the database tables of the old site was `ap_` and the new site was `wp_`. The problem arose with the Data Tables Generator by Supsystic plugin, which creates tables similar to Excel and can be used by inserting a shortcode on a page.

It turned out that all the tables in the site's database are now duplicated, since the Data Tables Generator by Supsystic plugin was used both on the previous site and on what I created and transferred.

That is, the shortcode `[supsystic table="10"]`, for example, outputs a table with the same shortcode of the old site, and not a new table, but at the same time I deleted in the database all tables related to the old site and this plugin with the prefix `ap_`. How is this even possible?